# Expo IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync with android.intent.action.VIEW

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I created an app with expo where some report in xlsx is generated in a server and then downloaded to the Download folder in Android. I want to "open" the file after it was downloaded by using another app with the open with native modal. I tried the following:

```
static openFile = async (asset, contentType) => {
    return IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
        data: asset.uri,
        type: contentType,
    });
};
```

(contentType is currently receiving '*/*') but it fails everytime with the following error:

> Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method startActivity on module ExpoIntentLauncher: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/report-10010654-20210304061930069176.xlsx exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

One solution is using the Sharing library, but I'm not overjoyed with it. Is there any way to make it work without ejecting from the managed flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem a month ago, I think it happens when startActivityAsync is called multiple times, my solution was to wrap my code in a try statement:

```
const data = await getContentUriAsync(uri)
try {
  await startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', { data, flags: 1 })
} catch (error) {}
```